# Using electric scooters to get to synagogue on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, kavod, electricity, orach-chaim

There is a principle in Halacha known as Kavod Habriyot, which essentially means rabbinic prohibitions can generally be violated for human dignity. My question is, if somebody has a hard time walking to synagogue (either cause it’s too far or too physically tasking), is there an issue with them using an electric scooter on Shabbat? So no lightbulb, but since normally  electricity is Derabbanan, could one use it for something like this under the umbrella of human dignity?

Comment: Just stay at home.

Comment: It's the old allow-anything-I-want-in-the-name-of-kavod-habriyot trick, Chief! I've seen it *millions* of times!

Comment: Gedola sakanta me'isura

Comment: Human dignity is not violated if someone cannot go to synagogue. This principle applies for things like tearing up toilet paper (not on the perforation) if you have nothing else on Shabbat. But having to stay home happens to everyone who is too sick to go out

Comment: What if someone lives alone and the isolation would be harmful to their mental health?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution is to use a "Shabbat Mode" scooter. The motor is always running at a set voltage and you use a clutch to engage it to the wheels.  A better question would be whether you could use a regular mobility scooter if the Shabbat Mode scooter didn't exist.

There is a precedent for ignoring Rabbinical laws for kavod Habruit. I recall a gemara that exempts this method of conveyance from carrying (at least in a karmelit).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M6pNBdS2i8w

Comment: Not all poskim, especially outside of Israel, hold that a "Shabbat mode" is actually halachically valid

Comment: Why is that youtube video there?

Comment: To demonstrate the kind of disabled person conveyance that is mentioned in the gemara.

Comment: But I have no idea why there is wrestling at the end

Comment: Perhaps offering a solution with no sources to back it is inappropriate in this context.

Comment: I take it back. It is outright inappropriate. No perhaps.